# Creating a stored procedure that uses (IF ELSE) to decide what goes in a new column

Tags: sql-server-2008, if-statement

I'm trying to create a stored procedure to show specific information that I need, however I don't have a column that says `Yes/No` when taking my dates into account.

Example...

I have a table with this info

```
|   ID   |   Name   |    DOB   |
|    1   |   John   | 1/1/1991 |
```

What I want to see is

```
|   ID   |   Name   |    DOB   |   Under 21   |
|    1   |   John   | 1/1/1991 |      No      |
```

I'm thinking that I need to me a temp table or something in order to incorporate that extra column, then use an if/else statement to decide on whether the DOB is greater than said date.

Does anyone have any pointers that they could help me with?

Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

you can try using a case like this

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(year,DOB,GETDATE()) < 21 THEN 'No'
ELSE 'Yes'
END AS 'Under 21'
FROM Table_Name
```